# CSS rounded table corners in Firefox -- issue

Tags: css, firefox, rounded-corners

Having an issue applying the rules that rounders the upper-left and upper-right corners in the top heading (one with red background) in Firefox 4.

http://jsfiddle.net/gFA4p/10/

Is there some sort of precedence issue that I'm missing?

Comment: FYI, it works in Chrome and Safari

Comment: Are you using IE8 or inferior?

Comment: Yeah, which browser(s) are you having trouble with specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works : http://jsfiddle.net/gFA4p/13/

Changed

```
#picksHeading{background-color:red}
```

to

```
#picksHeading th{background-color:red}
```

The ones you where try to round the edges on.

Also added :

```
-webkit-border-radius
-khtml-border-radius
```

Note for IE9 you have to decare all corners

```
.borderRightRadius {
border-radius:0 15px 0 0; 
}
.borderLeftRadius {
border-radius:15px 0 0 0; 
}
```

Previous versions of IE do not support border radius